# cbind puts 1 instead of character

Tags: r, cbind

I'm about to throw R out of the window. R is lovely, but sometimes a little problem takes hours to get solved.

Got this df:

```
Product <- c("Basket", "Basket", "Basket", "Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Corn", "Corn", "Corn", "Basket")
Place <- c("America", "Europe", "Africa", "America", "Europe", "Africa", "America", "Europe", "Africa", "America")
Detail <- c("Income", "Income", "Outcome", "Outcome", "Income", "Outcome", "Outcome", "Income", "Income", "Outcome")
Valuex <- c(1500, 2000, 2000, 4000, 5000, 700, 4000, 2000, 7000, 450)
df_test <- data.frame(Product, Place, Detail, Valuex, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then, I create another `data.frame` by doing this:

```
test <- df_test[1,]
```

At last, I use `cbind` like this:

```
test[1,1:4] <- cbind(df_test[1,1:2], "Prueba", df_test[1, 4])
```

And when I look into the data frame `test` I find this:

```
  Product   Place Detail Valuex
1  Basket America      1   1500
```

Instead of saving "Prueba", saves 1.

I've tried `as.character("Prueba")`, `c("Prueba")`, `paste("Prueba")`, but it still puts 1.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: just add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in your cbind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you keep seeing `1` in place of `Preuba`, is that the value is being converted to a factor, and you are seeing the level value.  You may avoid this by assigning the first row of `test` to a `cbind` call which has `stringsAsFactors` set to false, e.g.

```
test <- df_test[1,]
df <- cbind(df_test[1,1:2], "Prueba", df_test[1, 4], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
test[1,] <- df
test

  Product   Place Detail Valuex
1  Basket America Prueba   1500
```

### Demo

However, a possibly better workaround to your problem is to just assign a vector to the first row of the `test` data frame:

```
test[1,] <- c(df_test[1,1:2], "Prueba", df_test[1, 4])
```

Comment: @rawr Did you creators of R go out of their way to make types so complex?  Sometimes it feels this way.  Anyway, I updated my answer.

Comment: You don't know how much I thank you! You know I had tried with StringsAsFactors, but i had forgotten an "s": StringAsFactors... Thank you again! R stays indoor : )

Answer (score 0):

```
test[1,] = c(df_test[1,1:2], "Prueba", df_test[1, 4])
```

Comment: beat me by a minute

Comment: @qwr One minute and 24 seconds to be precise ;)